# React onChange() not working for dropdown values of a custom object when editing an object from a database

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When editing an existing Article object in the database, I can't change the dropdown value for Category. Category is an object which is a property (field) on my Article object.

I have researched a lot online but couldn't resolve this particular issue. I can successfully change the values and submit the changes for the String fields - e.g. article title and article text.

This is the code. The issue seems to be with handleChange() and/or `<Input type="select" name="category" ...>`

```
class ArticleEdit extends Component {

  emptyItem = {
    articleTitle: '',
    articleText: '',
    imageUrl: '',
    category: {},
    tags: []
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        item: this.emptyItem,
        categories: []
      };
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
     let allCategories = [];
      if (this.props.match.params.articleId !== 'new') {
        const article = await (await fetch(`/articles/${this.props.match.params.articleId}`)).json();

        fetch ('/categories')
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            }).then(data => {
            allCategories = data._embedded.categoryList.map(category => {
                return category
            });

            this.setState({item: article, categories: allCategories});
        });
      }
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value;
    let item = {...this.state.item};
    item[name] = value;
    this.setState({item});

    console.log("The category you selected is: " + item.category.categoryName);
    alert("The category you selected is: " + item.category.categoryName);
  }

  async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {item} = this.state;

    await fetch((item.articleId) ? '/articles/' + (item.articleId) : '/articles', {
      method: (item.articleId) ? 'PUT' : 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(item),
    });
    this.props.history.push('/articles');
  }

  render() {
    const {item} = this.state;

    const categoriesToDisplay = this.state.categories
    const categoryOptionItems = categoriesToDisplay.map(category =>
    <option key={category.categoryId} value={category.categoryName}>{category.categoryName}</option>
    );

    const title = <h2>{item.articleId ? 'Edit Article' : 'Create Article'}</h2>;

    return (
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <Container>
        {title}
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="articleTitle">Title</Label>
            <Input type="text" name="articleTitle" id="articleTitle" value={item.articleTitle || ''}
                   onChange={this.handleChange} autoComplete="name"/>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="articleText">Text</Label>
            <Input type="textarea" name="articleText" id="articleText" value={item.articleText || ''}
                   onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="imageUrl">Image URL</Label>
            <Input type="text" name="imageUrl" id="imageUrl" value={item.imageUrl || ''}
                   onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </FormGroup>
          <div className="row">
            <FormGroup className="col-md-6 mb-3">
              <Label for="category">Select Category</Label>
                <Input type="select" name="category" id="category" value={item.category.categoryName || ''}
                 onChange={value => this.handleChange({target : {name : 'categoryName', value}})}>
                  <option value="">Select</option>
                  {categoryOptionItems}
                </Input>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="col-md-6 mb-3">
              <Label for="taqs">Select Tag(s)</Label>
                <Input type="select" name="taqs" id="taqs" value={item.tags.map(tag => tag.tagName) || ''} onChange={this.handleChange} multiple>
                  <option>Depression</option>
                  <option>Anxiety</option>
                  <option>Phobias</option>
                  <option>Psychotherapy</option>
                  <option>Mindfulness</option>
                  <option>Religion</option>
                  <option>Supernatural</option>
                  <option>Healing</option>
                  <option>Eastern Practices</option>
                  <option>Motivation</option>
                  <option>Relationships</option>
                  <option>Positive Thinking</option>
                  <option>Emotions</option>
                  <option>Self-Help</option>
                  <option>Time Management</option>
                  <option>Learning From Experience</option>
                  <option>Personal Development Methods</option>
                </Input>
            </FormGroup>
          </div>
          <FormGroup className="float-right">
            <Button color="primary" type="submit">Save</Button>{' '}
            <Button color="secondary" tag={Link} to="/articles">Cancel</Button>
          </FormGroup>
        </Form>
      </Container>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click the 'Edit' button on my article list page and go to the page with the form of an existing article, I see my article category pre-selected in 'Select Category' dropdown.

When I try to select another category, it alerts and logs the name of the existing category, see https://ibb.co/k4sj1jq. After that, I see the existing category in the dropdown and can't change it.

How can I successfully select (and submit) a new category for this article?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This shows how to edit/create articles with 'Select' dropdown for category objects, properties of the article, and multiselect on click for tag objects on the article.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Button, Container, Form, FormGroup, Input, Label} from 'reactstrap';
import Header from './Header';
import Footer from './Footer';

class ArticleEdit extends Component {

  emptyItem = {
    articleTitle: '',
    articleText: '',
    imageUrl: '',
    category: {},
    tags: []
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        item: this.emptyItem,
        categories: [],
        allTags: []
      };
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.handleTagChange = this.handleTagChange.bind(this);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
     fetch ('/categories')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(data => this.setState({categories: data._embedded.categoryList}));

     fetch ('/tags')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(data => this.setState({allTags: data._embedded.tagList}));

     if (this.props.match.params.articleId !== 'new') {
       const article = await (await fetch(`/articles/view/${this.props.match.params.articleId}`)).json();
       this.setState({item: article});
     }
  }

  handleChange(event) {
     const target = event.target
     const name = target.name;
     const value = target.value;

     if (name === "category") {
     const categoryObject = this.state.categories.find(category => category.categoryId === Number(value));
        this.setState({
   item: Object.assign({}, this.state.item, {category: categoryObject})
     });
  } else {
  this.setState({
   item: Object.assign({}, this.state.item, {[name]: value})
     });
   }
  }

  handleTagChange(event) {
     let selectedTags = this.state.item.tags;
     const allTags = this.state.allTags;
     const value = event.target.value;
     let selectedTagIds = selectedTags.map(tag => tag.tagId);
        if (selectedTagIds.includes(Number(value))) {
            selectedTags = selectedTags.filter(t => t.tagId !== Number(value))
        } else {
            var newTagObject = allTags.find(tag => tag.tagId === Number(value))
            selectedTags.push(newTagObject)
        }
     this.setState({
            item: Object.assign({}, this.state.item, {tags: selectedTags})
     });
  }

  async handleSubmit(event) {
      if (this.validateFields()) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const {item} = this.state;
      await fetch((item.articleId) ? `/articles/${item.articleId}` : '/articles', {
          method: (item.articleId) ? 'PUT' : 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(item),
        });
      this.props.history.push('/articles');
      }
  }

  validateFields() {
     const {item} = this.state;

    if (item.articleText === "") {
       alert('Please provide text for the article');
       return false;
    }
    if (item.articleTitle === "") {
        alert('Please provide a title');
        return false;
     }
     if (!(item.category && Object.keys(item.category).length > 0)) {
        alert('Please select a category');
        return false;
     }
     return true;
  }

  render() {
    const {item} = this.state;

    const categoryOptions = this.state.categories.map(category =>
        <option key={category.categoryId} name={category.categoryName} value={category.categoryId}>{category.categoryName}</option>
        );

    const tagOptions = this.state.allTags.map(tag =>
        <option key={tag.tagId} name={tag.tagName} value={tag.tagId}>{tag.tagName}</option>
        );

    const title = <h2>{item.articleId ? 'Edit Article' : 'Create Article'}</h2>;

    return (
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <Container>
        {title}
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="articleTitle">Title</Label>
            <Input type="text" name="articleTitle" id="articleTitle" value={item.articleTitle || ''}
                   onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="articleText">Text</Label>
            <Input type="textarea" name="articleText" id="articleText" value={item.articleText || ''}
                   onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="imageUrl">Image URL</Label>
            <Input type="text" name="imageUrl" id="imageUrl" value={item.imageUrl || ''}
                   onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </FormGroup>
          <div className="row">
            <FormGroup className="col-md-6 mb-3">
              <Label for="category">Select Category</Label>
              <Input type="select" name="category" id="category"
              value={(item.category && Object.keys(item.category).length > 0) ? item.category.categoryId : 0} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <option>Select</option>
                {categoryOptions}
              </Input>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="col-md-6 mb-3">
              <Label for="tags">Select Tag(s)</Label>
                <Input type="select" name="tags" id="tags" value={item.tags.map(tag => tag.tagId)} onClick={this.handleTagChange} multiple>
                  {tagOptions}
                </Input>
            </FormGroup>
          </div>
          <FormGroup className="float-right">
            <Button color="primary" type="submit">Save</Button>{' '}
            <Button color="secondary" tag={Link} to="/articles">Cancel</Button>
          </FormGroup>
        </Form>
      </Container>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(ArticleEdit);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onChange={value => this.handleChange({target : {name : 'categoryName', value}})}
```

I believe onChange function for categories will be receiving event, not value. You can simplify by

```
<Input name="categoryName" onChange={this.handleChange} > { options } </Input>
```

OR

replace onChange function with the following

```
onChange={e => 
  this.handleChange({
    ...e,
    target: {
      ...e.target,
      name: 'categoryName'
    }
  })
}
```

One issue that I noticed is the way you setting `fetch ('/categories')` response is not proper.

```
fetch ('/categories')
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(r => this.setState({ categories: r }));
```

This makes sure that category in state will be set only after fetch call is resolved.

Comment: Hi Ajay, thank you for your response. Both ways allow for the new category to be seen in the select box after selecting. I still get the alert and the console log for the old category and after clicking 'Save' the old category stays.

Comment: Can you tell me where this Input component is coming from? Is it a component you created or are you using any library ??

Comment: It's from Reactstrap.

Comment: Can you check whether Category input is getting changed input. put a console inside render to show this.state.category.categoryName and see whether its changing on input change.

Comment: It's not changing. It logs the old category and returns it in the select box after I click out of it.

Comment: Even this part is not changing after selectChange ???
`console.log("The category you selected is: " + item.category.categoryName); alert("The category you selected is: " + item.category.categoryName);`

Comment: Do console event.target and event.value inside handleSubmit and see it's getting value onChange

Comment: The alert in handleChange(), and the logs in handleChange() and render() all give me the old category.
I'll log these new things in handleSubmit() and will let you know :) In a couple of hours I'll have the chance to do that.

Comment: Do console event.target and event.value inside handleSubmit and see it's getting value onChange.
Please do this. I think handleChange is not receiving the latest value and it's not updating the state somehow.

Comment: I logged both in handleSubmit(), before and after PUT and history push.
I get this after I click Save: https://ibb.co/yg4dB9b

Comment: Did you change this part ?
onChange={value => this.handleChange({target : {name : 'categoryName', value}})}
onChange callback will be receiving event itself as argument, not value.

Comment: In my Input now I have name = "categoryName" and onChange is the same as your second option (after the 'OR' in your original answer). The rest in my Input is the same as before.

Comment: No need to do the last one. If you are giving name as categoryName, then using `<Input name="categoryName" onChange={this.handleChange} > { options } </Input>` is fine. May be that synthetic error is appearing because we were messing with event object.

Comment: Using `render() {
    const {item} = this.state;
    const categoryOptions = this.state.categories.map(category =>
    <option key={category.categoryId} value={category.categoryName}>{category.categoryName}</option>    );

    const title = <h2>{item.articleId ? 'Edit Article' : 'Create Article'}</h2>;
    console.log("The category you selected is: " + item.categoryName);`
and
`<Input type="select" name="categoryName" id="category"
   onChange={this.handleChange}>
  <option value="">Select</option>
  {categoryOptions}
</Input>`
I end up with 2 categories for the item in state.

Comment: https://ibb.co/JR90dHp
And the existing value is not preselected.
The console for render() logs the new category.
The value for categoryOptions map ->  value={category.categoryName} doesn’t associate the categoryName to the item (article), just pulls the category name from the database. This seems to be the issue.

Comment: Using the same for render() and 
`<Input type="select" name="category" id="category"
                   onChange={e =>
                              this.handleChange({
                                ...e,
                                target: {
                                  ...e.target,
                                  name: 'categoryName'
                                }
                              })
                            }>
                  <option value="">Select</option>
                  {categoryOptions}
                </Input>`

Comment: I again have 2 categories in state but item.categoryName is undefined

Comment: Can we move this chat to slack or something? I am sorry, I'm not getting the correct picture here or I must be missing something.

Comment: https://join.slack.com/t/inspiremehq/shared_invite/enQtNjcyOTY0MzI4NzEwLWJkMTI5YzllMmQ0Mzc4NGM0MGM0Y2Q5N2MxZmZkMGNmODkwNmQ2Nzg5YmUzNDU5NmU3ZTNjOGJhYjdlNzU0Y2Q Thank you :)